# Getting a URL from current webpage in Qt WebView

Tags: qt, webview, tabs

I have a QWebView inside a QTabWidget, and I'd like to know how to get the URL of the web page you're currently on so that I can:

- Update the URL bar to show the current URL, dur
- Display the name of the page as the tab name

So far, my tabs simply display the first page they load (google.co.uk), but I don't know how to change the name to the current URL when the user clicks a link.

Is there a better way to show the tab name? Or shall I just split the URL and take the name from there?

Answer (score 1):

```
WebView {
    id: webview

    url: "google.co.uk"

    onUrlChanged: {
        console.log("WebView UrlChange: ", url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
view = new QWebView();
connect(view,SIGNAL(linkClicked(QUrl)),this,SLOT(urlchange(QUrl)));

void WebviewItem::urlchange(QUrl &url) 
{
qDebug()<<"linkClicked in Qt "<<url;
 }
```

Comment: I imagined it had something to do with QUrl, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger from the loadFinished event for after a page is loaded

```
void LoginDialog::on_webViewLogin_loadFinished(bool arg1)
{
    QUrl myurl = ui->webViewLogin->url(); // grab current webview url & show
    //.... other declarations etc
    messageBox.critical( 0, "Error", myurl.toString() );
}
```